# Why shared_ptr didn't make raw pointer NULL?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I want to understand shared_ptr better
This is my code

```
struct A {
  int val_ = 0;
  A(int val) : val_(val) { std::cout << "A(" << val_ << ")" << std::endl ; }
  ~A() { std::cout << "~A(" << val_ << ")" << std::endl ; }

};

int main() {
  {
    A* a_raw  = new A(2);
    shared_ptr<A> a2(a_raw); 
    {
      shared_ptr<A> a3(new A(3));
      std::cout << "log 2" << std::endl;
      a2 = a3;
      std::cout << "log 3" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "log 4" << std::endl;
    if (a_raw == nullptr) {
        cout << "A_raw is nullptr" << std::endl;
    } else {
        cout << "A_raw ---------" << a_raw->val_ << std::endl;
    }
  }
```

Current output

```
A(2)
A(3)
log 2
~A(2)
log 3
log 4
A_raw ---------0
~A(3)
```

Destructor ~A(2) was called because of line `a2 = a3;`
Could you please elaborate logic of `operator=` ?

**Why do I see line** `A_raw ---------0` ??
I expected `A_raw is nullptr`

Did I understand copy assignment correctly

```
class my_shared_ptr {
    ...
    my_shared_ptr& operator=(const my_shared_ptr& other) {
        if (counter_ and *counter_ > 1) {
            *counter_ -= 1;
        } else {
            delete ptr_;
        }
        
        ptr_ = other.ptr_;
        counter_ = other.counter_;
        if (other.ptr_ != nullptr) {
            *counter_ += 1;
        }
    }
private:
    T* ptr_ = nullptr;
    size_t* counter_ = nullptr;
```

Comment: That's not how smart pointers are supposed to work. They take ownership of the object or data that the pointer is pointing to, but otherwise leave the pointer alone. The correct watyto handle such a pointer is to forget it in your code, just don't use it again.

Comment: Change your code to this: `shared_ptr<A> a2(exchange(a_raw, nullptr));`

Comment: `operator=` is simple - `a=b` causes `a` to release the ownership of the object currently held (if any), and share the ownership of the object held by `b`. Releasing the ownership may or may not cause that object to be destroyed (depending on whether there's another `shared_ptr` still owning it).

Comment: `shared_ptr` constructor from raw pointer takes that raw pointer by value. So it's physically impossible for it to set `a_raw` to `nullptr`, or modify it in any other way. In your example, `a_raw->val_` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended (in other words, `a_raw` is a dangling pointer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that `a_raw` is not `nullptr` isn't related to the assignment `a3=a2`:

`A* a_raw  = new A(2);` will allocate a new A on the free store and there will be some memory on the stack that holds the address of that object.

`shared_ptr<A> a2(a_raw);` will take that address by value. That way it's a copy of the address and `a2` has no way of modifying the original `a_raw`.

Therefore it will never be possible to set `a_raw` to `nullptr`.

---

What does the assignment `a2 = a3` do?

Well, [operator =](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D) says:

> Replaces the managed object with the one managed by r.
>
> If *this already owns an object and it is the last shared_ptr owning it, and r is not the same as *this, the object is destroyed through the owned deleter.

So, before taking over the new ownership, `a2` will decrement the reference count of the resource. In your case, the reference count drops to 0, so the object A(2) is destroyed.

It then takes ownership of `a3`, which increments the reference count from 1 to 2, since `a2` and `a3` are now managing the same resource. You have successfully shared a pointer - which is exactly what a `shared_ptr` does.

As mentioned earlier, there's no way for the shared pointer to set your original `a_raw` to `nullptr` because they don't have a reference to it.

---

The idea of smart pointers it that you don't deal with raw pointers at all. You should be able to get rid of `A*` completely. So it's best to not have a raw pointer in the first place:

```cpp
int main() {
{
    shared_ptr<A> a2(new A(2)); 
    {
      shared_ptr<A> a3(new A(3));
      std::cout << "log 2" << std::endl;
      a2 = a3;
      std::cout << "log 3" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "log 4" << std::endl;
}
```

or even use `make_shared` so that you never attempt to search for the matching `delete` statements for your `new` statements.

```cpp
int main() {
{
    shared_ptr<A> a2 = make_unique<A>(2); 
    {
      shared_ptr<A> a3= make_unique<A>(3);
      std::cout << "log 2" << std::endl;
      a2 = a3;
      std::cout << "log 3" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "log 4" << std::endl;
}
```

---

Regarding the updated question about the copy assignment:

- from the given code, I don't see where `counter_` is initialized.
- the method is missing a `return` statement and it's quite important what it returns.
- `*counter_ -= 1;` - if counter `== 0` after this operation, the pointer should be `delete`d. Since you probably need the cleanup code in several places, it would be best making that a private method.
- Checking for `nullptr` in `if (other.ptr_ != nullptr)` is not necessary, IMHO. Since you can `delete` a `nullptr`, you just keep track of its reference like any other pointer.

Comment: Did you mean A(2) ? 
>>  the reference count drops to 0, so the object A(3) is destroyed.

Comment: Did I implement copy assignment correctly? (updated the question)

Comment: @mascai: oh, I got the assignment the wrong way round. Thanks.